# How to change template variable to a specific type or don't let it become a null pointer

Tags: c++, node.js, templates, pointers

I'm developing a libcurl binding for nodejs, and I hit a small roadblock.

To call the function `curl_easy_getinfo` from a curl handler, I'm using the following template function:

```cpp
template<typename ResultType, typename v8MappingType>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Curl::GetInfoTmpl( const Curl &obj, int infoId )
{
    ResultType result;

    CURLINFO info = (CURLINFO) infoId;
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_getinfo( obj.curl, info, &result );

    if ( code != CURLE_OK )
        return Curl::Raise( "curl_easy_getinfo failed!", curl_easy_strerror( code ) );

    return v8MappingType::New( result );
}
```

It's called like this:

```
retVal = Curl::GetInfoTmpl<char*, v8::String>( *(obj), infoId );
```

From the libcurl documentation:

> CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH
>
> Pass a pointer to a char pointer to receive a pointer to a string
>   holding the path of the entry path. That is the initial path libcurl
>   ended up in when logging on to the remote FTP server. **This stores a
>   NULL as pointer if something is wrong.** (Added in 7.15.4)
>
> Also works for SFTP since 7.21.4

Ok, if I try to call getInfo( CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH ) from javascript land, that null pointer is making the node script exit with code -1073741819.

What is the workaround to place a empty string as result in there?

```
template<typename ResultType, typename v8MappingType>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Curl::GetInfoTmpl( const Curl &obj, int infoId )
{
    ResultType result;

    CURLINFO info = (CURLINFO) infoId;
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_getinfo( obj.curl, info, &result );

    //workaround for null pointer, aka, hack
    if ( infoId == CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH && result == NULL ) {
        //what to place here to change result to an empty string?
       //this section is always going to be called only when ResultType = char*
    }

    if ( code != CURLE_OK )
        return Curl::Raise( "curl_easy_getinfo failed!", curl_easy_strerror( code ) );

    return v8MappingType::New( result );
}
```

I've just started to learn C++, so feel free to make any commentary about the code.

---

So, after searching, I found out about template specializations, and so created one for the function above, however, this basically generated two functions with almost the same signature, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned about template specialization, and used it to solve this problem:

```cpp
template<typename ResultType, typename v8MappingType>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Curl::GetInfoTmpl( const Curl &obj, int infoId )
{
    v8::HandleScope scope;

    ResultType result;

    CURLINFO info = (CURLINFO) infoId;
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_getinfo( obj.curl, info, &result );

    if ( code != CURLE_OK )
        return Curl::Raise( "curl_easy_getinfo failed!", curl_easy_strerror( code ) );

    return scope.Close( v8MappingType::New( result ) );
}

template<> //template specialization
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Curl::GetInfoTmpl<char*,v8::String>( const Curl &obj, int infoId )
{
    v8::HandleScope scope;

    char *result;

    CURLINFO info = (CURLINFO) infoId;
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_getinfo( obj.curl, info, &result );

    if ( !result ) { //null pointer
        return scope.Close( v8::String::New( "" ) );
    }

    if ( code != CURLE_OK )
        return Curl::Raise( "curl_easy_getinfo failed!", curl_easy_strerror( code ) );

    return scope.Close( v8::String::New( result ) );
}
```

The code was mostly duplicated, but at least the issue was resolved. If anyone have a better way to solve that, feel free to post it.

---

Still not happy with the code above, I asked for help on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/50943/template-function-specialization-with-code-duplication), and [@michael-urman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89999/michael-urman) helped me with it, using specialization on a traits class, here we go:

```cpp
// traits class to determine whether to do the check
template <typename> struct ResultCanBeNull : std::false_type {};
template <> struct ResultCanBeNull<char*> : std::true_type {};

template<typename ResultType, typename v8MappingType>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Curl::GetInfoTmpl( const Curl &obj, int infoId )
{
    v8::HandleScope scope;

    ResultType result;

    CURLINFO info = (CURLINFO) infoId;
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_getinfo( obj.curl, info, &result );

    // use the traits class to filter in or out the null pointer check
    if ( ResultCanBeNull<ResultType>::value && !result ) { //null pointer
        return v8::String::New( "" );
    }

    if ( code != CURLE_OK )
        return Curl::Raise( "curl_easy_getinfo failed!", curl_easy_strerror( code ) );

    return scope.Close( v8MappingType::New( result ) );
}
```

No duplication!